# JavaScript API Response - Check if variable exists

Tags: javascript

In an API response, I want to check if a variable exists. If it doesn't, I want to assign it a blank value:

```
if(!data3.fields[i+2].values.value[0]) {
  data3.fields[i+2].values.value[0] = "";
} else {
  break;
}
```

Error in the console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

This confuses me because I thought that's exactly what my if the statement was checking. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: `data`, `fields`,`fields[i+2]`,`values` or `value` could all be undefined in that query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 1):

The `if` check won't protect you from trying to use an undefined variable. In your instance the `values` property is `undefined`. If you wanted to test for that you would need to first check that specific property

```
if(data3.fields[i+2].values !== undefined && data3.fields[i+2].values.value[0]){
   //do something with data3.fields[i+2].values.value[0]
}
```

additionally, if you are in a scenario where you don't even know if data3 exists (for example you are checking for the existence of a third party script, or something else in your environment) you would need to use the `typeof` operator to be safe. E.G.

```
if(typeof(ga) !== 'undefined'){ //typeof returns a string. This would be testing for google analytics on a page.
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work like PHP does (which checks the whole 'chain'). In your example, you actually check if `.value[0]` of `values` exists, but dont check if `values` exists. The full version should be:

```
  if( data3 && && data3.fields[i+2] && data3.fields[i+2].values && !data3.fields[i+2].values.value[0]) {}
```

In your code `ata3.fields[i+2].values` is undefined, and you're trying to access `value[0]` of 'undefined'

---

Or slightly more simplefied, if you wand to test if `d` has a value, you have to make sure that `a`, `b` and `c` aldo have a value:

```
if( a && a.b && a.b.c && !a.b.c.d){ /* ... */ }
```

You can remove checks on the left side of the checks if you are sure those exist. E.g.: If you know that `a.b` *always* exist, you can simplefy:

```
if( a.b.c && !a.b.c.d){ /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make sure the complete property chain is not undefined you have to check every single step and the later ones won't be executed if at least `&&` condition is false.

```
if (data3 && data3.fields && data3.fields[i+2] && data3.fields[i+2].values && data3.fields[i+2].values.value && data3.fields[i + 2].values.value[0]) {
  data3.fields[i + 2].values.value[0] = "";
} else {
  break;
}
```

Another way would be to just do it and catch the exception:

```
try {
  data3.fields[i + 2].values.value[0] = "";
} catch (e) {
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `data3.fields[i+2].values` is `undefined`. You can't check for a property `.value` on `undefined`.

You'd need to verify each property/index belongs along the way if you always want that nested path to default to an empty string.

```
if (data3.fields[i+2] === undefined) {
  data.fields[i+2] = {};
}

if (data3.fields[i+2].values === undefined) {
  data3.fields[i+2].values = {};
}

if (data3.fields[i+2].values.value === undefined) {
  data3.fields[i+2].values.value = [];
}

// and finally your empty string assignment
if (data3.fields[i+2].values.value[0] === undefined) {
  data3.fields[i+2].values.value[0] = '';
}
```

---

Depending on your requirements, you might be able to get away with assigning a stub as soon as you know `data3.fields[i+2]` is `undefined`.

```
if (data3.fields[i+2] === undefined) {
  data3.fields[i+2] = {
    values: {
      value: ['']
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: what if any of those are `null`?

Comment: If you needed to accommodate null, the conditions would be made less restrictive. In OPs question, `data3.fields[i+2]` is `undefined`, not null, so everything following that would be too. Consider using something like lodash's [isNil](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isNil)

Comment: If you just replace `if (data3.fields[i+2] === undefined)` with `if (data3.fields[i+2])` it will cater for both

Comment: I think you mean `! data3.fields[i+2]`, but such a change would also catch `false`, `''`, `0`, etc...